# Can I make Snowflake create stage from all CSV columns and first row as headers?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

At the moment, when I create a stage from a CSV, I need to ***manually*** specify the columns by $column_position and then aliasing each.

e.g. CSV headers: employer_code, employer_name...etc.
Select Statement: SELECT $1 employer_code, $2, employer_name... etc.

I've been looking through the options in the documentation and searching for this answer, but I can't seem to find options that will basically take;

1. every column in the CSV, and
2. the first row of data as the header value

This seems like it should be something that's available OoTB, but can't see how to work it.

Any clues?

Thx in advance.

Comment: We could write a store procedure to work this out, but the name of columns is only one of the complexities: How would it guess the type of each column?  (there are tools that help with this, btw)

Comment: For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/61921349/132438, with Python.  This online tool will generate the create table for you from a sample csv https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm  (and there are many more tools available)

Comment: I'd be happy to have them read in as strings, and do casting and string manipulation (which I am comfortable with from my VBA days! :P )

Answer (score 0):

Find here a Snowflake that basically does what you are requesting:

> https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/Excelerator/blob/master/SnowflakeExcelAddin_Stored_Procedures.sql

The name of the UDF is `create_table_from_file_and_load_work()` - it does it's best to guess headers and data types from the staged file.

It allows you to use the first row of the file for the data types, or the name of the columns:

> ```
>   firstColumnFromFirstowFromFile = arrayFirstRow[0].toUpperCase();
> ```
>
> // Check to see if the first col is a datatype. If not then its' the column headers

If the type of each column is not provided, the UDF `get_datatype()` is called - which makes its best guess.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I'm only a beginner, so was hoping for some easy OoTB option. I'll take a look at that solution once I have some experience with stored procedures, and a bit more confidence!

Comment: You won't need to do much more than create the stored procedures in your db, and then call them.